# NLog dotnet core 2.1 mail ignoring level

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-core, nlog

I have NLog running in a .net core 2.1 app and my file and mail loggers are working but for some reason the mail logger is sending everything regardless of the level set - nlog.config below

```xml
<logger name="*" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="mail" />

<!--Skip non-critical Microsoft logs and so log only own logs-->
<logger name="Microsoft.*" maxLevel="Info" final="true" />


<logger name="*" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="ownFile-web" />
```

For instance "ownFile-web" is working perfectly and only logs ERROR and FATAL messages but "mail" is sending me everything (INFO - every request and DB operation) which is not what I want and obviously slows down the app

I'm new to NLog so maybe I've done something wrong in the config?

I also set this in Program.cs hoping to set a global log level of Warning and above but this didn't help:

```
        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.ClearProviders();
            logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Warning);

        }).UseNLog();
```

Comment: maybe the program is reading an old nlog.config? (e.g. in bin folder?). The code/config above looks good

Comment: You were kinda right about the bin folder - I wasn't cleaning the solution every time so it got out of sync - had to do this to make it work for me:  <when condition="level > LogLevel.Debug" action="Log" />
        <when condition="level == LogLevel.Info" action="Ignore" />

Answer (score 0):

For some reason "minLevel" was getting ignored - I found these when conditionals and it started behaving properly:

```
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="mail">
  <filters>
    <when condition="level > LogLevel.Debug" action="Log" />
    <when condition="level == LogLevel.Info" action="Ignore" />
  </filters>
</logger>
```

Comment: that's strange. Also note that this less performant than "minLevel". If you still has the issue of the ignoring minlevel, check the internal log